# XPath-Problems when selecting a attribute of a XML-Tag

Tags: xml, xpath

I could use a little help with an XPath-Expression. check the code below; how do I select the attribute "idc" at the shown point?

```
<!-- XML-Code -->
<pictGaleList>
    <item>
    </item>

    <dateItem>
        <ImageDate idc="20">
            20/04/2010
        </ImageDate>
    </dateItem>

</pictGaleList>


<!-- XSLT -->

<xsl:template match="pictGaleList">
    <xsl:value-of select="" /> <!-- here I need the value of the attribute "idc" -->
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dateItem/ImageDate/@idc` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
dateItem[position() = 1]/ImageDate/@idc
```

Will give you the value of **1st** ImageDate element's idc attribute inside `pictGaleList`

Answer (score 0):

Solved, the false behaviour if the website didn't come from this code. nvrmnd